# Unable to get the all active subscriptions from Google Play

Tags: android, android-billing, android-subscriptionmanager

Please help me to figure out what I'm missing.

I have an Android App which has a few subscriptions products, in total we have 5 subscriptions (two in use, the rest for internal purposes), all of the are active and have the same configuration settings

Although when I try to retrieve all available subscriptions, I'm getting only the subset of them, 2 from 5 subscriptions. I can't figure out what is wrong with the 3 another which I don't get.

I'm using the following third party lib to interact with the Play Store
https://github.com/serso/android-checkouk, not sure that another lib like com.android.billingclient:billing will fix it, all of them are based on the same low level tier

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try Play Billing Library. Google Play has announced that PBL is the only way to integrate with Play in-app billing. Some action might be taken to enforce that.